# Asp.net mail sending + from id is over written by smtp user id

Tags: .net, asp.net, email, sendmail, smtpclient

I have an issue in my asp.net application. I am using SMTP server credentials to send emails. It includes a hostname smtp.gmail.com, port no=587, username=”somemailaddress@gmail.com” password=””. I have created a mail message object and set the from and to address to “from@gmail.com”,”to@gmail.com”. I am getting emails, but the from id is always taken as the username ie,somemailaddress@gmail.com. How it happens? How can I change the email address to from@gmail.com?

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens on the gmail servers. The idea being that they dont want you to send emails from gmail accounts looking like you sent it from another account. Thats one of the ways they combat SPAM. You can use Google Apps if the idea is to send email messages like they were coming from your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you mentioned some examples using Google Apps?

Comment: http://www.google.com/apps/ You will find all the information you need here. They even have a free version, if 50 email accounts are enough for you. All you need to do is signup and verify you own the domain.